# How to use django-tastypie with django-axes

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-authentication

Settings:

```
django==1.8
django-tastypie==0.13
django-axes==2.3
```

I've got login resource through tastypie what looks like below

```
from django.contrib.auth import login


class LoginResource(Resource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'login'
        allowed_methods = ['post']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        form = AuthForm(data=bundle.data)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
            if form.get_user():
                login(bundle.request, form.get_user())
                raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=HttpResponse(status=200))
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=http.HttpBadRequest(status=400))
```

And I can't figure out how to log these login attempts in django-axes.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution was next: I write custom login view in `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login


def core_login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["authentication_form"] = AuthForm
    return login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And in tastypie resource:

```
from core.views import core_login

class LoginResource(Resource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'login'
        allowed_methods = ['post']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.request.POST = bundle.data
        if core_login(bundle.request).status_code == 302:
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=HttpResponse(status=200))
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=http.HttpBadRequest(status=400))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at the code from `django-axes`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/2.3.3/axes/apps.py#L11) we can see it uses a decorator called `watch_login` to provide its functionality.

To log the login attempts using your resource you will have to apply that decorator to the `view` that is called when the user tries to login using that given resource.

Based on `tastypie` code, you could override `prepend_urls` method of your resource and add your url. Like this (this is just an example, wasn't tested):

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    from axes.decorators import watch_login
    urls = [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login$" % (self._meta.resource_name,), watch_login(self.wrap_view('dispatch_list')), name="login-enpoint")
    ]
    return urls
```